# Using Lodash chaining, how can I return a filtered array of objects while mapping over an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, lodash

I've got object of filters that look like this:

```
var filterUpdate = {
 assetClass: [{id: 1, name: 'photo'}, {id: 2, name: 'thumbnail'} ]
 vehicleType: [{id: 1, name: 'nissan'}]
}
```

I've got state data like this (the keys representing years are dynamic and can change):

```
this.state.filteredOwnership = {
 2020: [],
 2021: [{assetClass: 'thumbnail', vehicleType: 'Toyota' }, {assetClass: 'Abs', vehicleType: 'Prius' }]
 2022: [{assetClass: 'thumbnail', vehicleType: 'Toyota' }, {assetClass: 'photo', vehicleType: 'Prius' }, {assetClass: 'Abs', vehicleType: 'nissan'}, {assetClass: 'LMO', vehicleType: 'Tesla'} ]
}
```

This is the present lodash chain:

```
const filterData = _filter(filteredOwnership, (dataitem)=> {

  if(_isEmpty(filterUpdate.assetClass) && _isEmpty(filterUpdate.vehicleType)) {
    return dataitem
  }

  if(_some(_map(filterUpdate.assetClass, 'name'), dataitem.assetClass)  || _some(_map(filterUpdate.vehicleType, 'name'), dataitem.vehicleType)){
    return dataitem
  }
  
});
```

We want to return a filtered array that would look like this:

```
filterData = {
   2020: [],
   2021: [{assetClass: 'thumbnail', vehicleType: 'Toyota' }]
   2022: [{assetClass: 'thumbnail', vehicleType: 'Toyota' }, {assetClass: 'photo', vehicleType: 'Prius' }, {assetClass: 'Abs', vehicleType: 'nissan' } ]
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `dataitem.assetClass` and `dataitem.vehicleType` are the array of objects from within the year keys.  I don't know where to use _map on dataitem that would help me return an item with in that array to be filtered

**I am also open to non lodash suggestions!  Regular js ways to do it would also be appreciated!**

Comment: Do the arrays `.assetClass` and .`vehicleType` only have one object, always?

Comment: Can you simply explain how `filterUpdate` helps to map `filteredOwnership` to what you want ? It's really difficult to understand.

Comment: @testing_22 filterUpdate will always have assetClass and vehicleType as attributes though they may be empty arrays if there are no filters. When a filter is selected, those arrays will be filled with a filter object and they can have multiple objects like so

E.g. filterUpate = {assetType: [], vehicleType: [{id: 1, name: ‘Nissan’}, {id: 1, name: ‘Tesla’}}

Comment: @KavinduVindika filter update doesn’t map filterOwnership currently, it maps each filter in filterUpdate and compares it to filterOwnership, which is currently an array of objects. I need to find a way to map filterOwnership so that filterUpdate can compare compare to each individual filterOwnership object in its array.

Comment: If you run your code against one specific year record from `filteredOwnership`, does it work, right? So the problem is to map the _filter to each year?

Comment: @testing_22  just tested it, no it doesn't work.  Im having issues debugging this deep in the chain, but passing just as single year as filterOwnership (such as the array you will see in 2021), the _some if conditional is still coming out false.  filterUpdate.assetClass in ```(_some(_map(filterUpdate.assetClass, 'name'), dataitem.assetClass)``` will give us the object such as ```{id: 1, name: 'photo'}``` and the dataitem,assetClass will be ```"photo"```, but I wonder if the ```'name'``` param being passed to the map function is doing anything to give us the assetClass string.

Comment: ended up with this as a solution:

```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working:

```
const filterUpdate = {
  assetClass: [
    { id: 1, name: "photo" },
    { id: 2, name: "thumbnail" }
  ],
  vehicleType: [{ id: 1, name: "nissan" }]
};

const filteredOwnership = {
  2020: [],
  2021: [
    { assetClass: "thumbnail", vehicleType: "Toyota" },
    { assetClass: "Abs", vehicleType: "Prius" }
  ],
  2022: [
    { assetClass: "thumbnail", vehicleType: "Toyota" },
    { assetClass: "photo", vehicleType: "Prius" },
    { assetClass: "Abs", vehicleType: "nissan" },
    { assetClass: "LMO", vehicleType: "Tesla" }
  ]
};

const filters = normalizeFilters(filterUpdate);
const byYear = filterBy(filteredOwnership, filters);

function normalizeFilters(filterObj) {
  let filters = {};
  Object.keys(filterObj).forEach((key) => {
    filters[key] = filterObj[key].map((it) => it.name);
  });
  return filters;
}

function filterBy(ownershipInYear, filters) {
  const filteredByYear = {};

  for (const year of Object.keys(ownershipInYear)) {
    const ownership = filteredOwnership[year];

    const inYear = [];
    for (const key in filters) {
      const filtered = ownership.filter((it) => filters[key].includes(it[key]));
      inYear.push(filtered);
    }
    filteredByYear[year] = inYear.flat();
  }

  return filteredByYear;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).